# Return the greatest of 3 float values in Ada

Tags: ada

I'm trying to create a subprogram that receives 3 float values and returns the greatest of the 3.

My code:

```
procedure is

   function Biggest(A, B, C: in Float) return Float is 
      
      X: Float; -- Greatest value
      
   begin
      
      X:= Float'Max(B, C);
      if A <= X then
         null;
      else
         X:= A;
      end if;         
          
      return Float'Ceiling(X); 
      
   end Biggest;

A, B, C: Float;
begin 

   Put("Mata in tre flyttal: ");
   Get(A);
   Get(B);
   Get(C);
   Put("Det största av dessa värden är: ");
   Put(Biggest(A,B,C), Fore=>0, Aft=>0, Exp=>0);
```

I dont really understand where I went wrong.

Comment: What does it do, and what do you expect it to do? What's wrong with `return Float'Floor (Float'Max (Float'Max (A, B), C) );`?

Comment: I'm not really sure what it does right now but what I wanted it to do was to check which one of A, B and C has the greatest value and return the greatest value. 
So X:= Float'Max(B, C) returns the greater of the 2 values. If A is less or equal to X it shouldnt change anything and the greatest value is between B or C. And if A is greater than B and C then X:= A.

Comment: In other words, and as you said in your original question, return the greatest of the three parameter values. Then why do you have Float'Floor? You did not say that you wanted rounding or flooring to an integral value... Try to remove the Float'Floor and see if it then works as you want.

Comment: It doesnt really change a thing, Float'Floor is just rounding it down as far as I know? 
let me edit and show the rest of my code, since it seems like when B is the greatest value I dont get the greatest value back

Comment: How do you know which it returns when it does not necessarily return any of them?

Comment: i'm not really sure what you mean? Whichever value it does return will get rounded down. Or am I missing your question?

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is overly complicated.

Just set 'X' (bad name by the way) to A, then compare the others to X.

So...

```
    Big : Float = A;
begin
    if B > Big then Big := B; end if;
    if C > Big then Big := C; end if;
    return Big;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Alright idk what changed but its working now. The only change I made is to change the Float'Rounding to Float'Ceiling which I doubt made it work.